# Is Occlusion culling enabled in threejs by default

Tags: three.js, occlusion-culling

Is occlusion culling enabled in threejs by default or there is any setting in threejs where I can enable it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A form of occlusion culling is enabled by default in three.js.

`WebGLRenderer` has a property `renderer.sortObjects`, which defaults to `true`.

When `true`, opaque objects (those having `material.transparent` equal to `false`) are sorted based on distance from the camera, and the opaque objects closest to the camera are rendered first.

If `renderer.sortObjects` is set to `false`, then opaque objects are rendered in the order they appear in the scene graph.

In addition, `Object3D.renderOrder` can also be used to control the rendering order.

three.js r.75

Comment: with custom occlusion culling can I get enhanced performance ??

Comment: In theory you can, but whether such improvement is measurable depends on the nature of your scene.